# Can't refresh my access_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying for hours to get a new access token from the Google API but it kept throwing me a 400 error : bad request. Any idea ?

```
r = RestClient.post 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', :refresh_token => refresh_token, :client_id => client_id, :client_secret => client_secret, :grant_type => 'access_token'
```

**EDIT :** Do I need to force  content-type ? Do you have an alternative solution to RestClient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grant_type` should be "**refresh_token**" and not
    "**access_token**"

Try this:

```
RestClient.post 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', :refresh_token => refresh_token, :client_id => client_id, :client_secret => client_secret, :grant_type => 'refresh_token'
```

Comment: Yeah, figured it out the day after. Thx